# Div'ы в блоке

Tags: jquery

Напомните, как выглядит функция которая вызывается при клике на вложенные дивы селектора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#selector').on('click', 'div', function(){})
```

[$.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)